# QuantLib installation fatal error C1083 boost/config.hpp & boost/test/unit_test.hpp

Tags: boost, installation, quantlib

I know this issue has been discussed here before. But after I followed the suggestions and added the paths via Visual Studio, I'm still stuck:

In VS, I have:
Additional Include Directories: C:\local\boost_1_58_0 
Additional Library Directories: C:\local\boost_1_58_0\libs

When I built QuantLib within VS, I could see C:\local\boost_1_58_0 is among the included paths. I can also see the valid config.hpp file in C:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost and unit_test.hpp in C:\local\boost_1_58_0\boost\test. Nevertheless I still got the C1083 error.

Have been stuck for 2+ days, I'm puzzled how to get around this. Any advice?

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: 2013 Professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the official instructions at http://quantlib.org/install/vc10.shtml.  In VS 10 and beyond, include and library paths are set through the Property Manager.  Steps 5 and 6 in the instructions linked above describe the procedure.  You might want to exit and restart the IDE to make sure that the changes are saved.

Comment: Thanks much, Luigi.  Yes, setting through the Property Manager works, not through the Project menu.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for the location of Property Manager and using VS2015 - I found it on the fourth tab at the bottom of the Solution Explorer pane, please see image attached.  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYLFk.jpg)

Comment: you may pull the image in your answer instead of external link